# Back to main menu button

Tags: button, menu, program-entry-point, back

Please help me with creating button to main menu in different plugins. For now I just have created 1 in on plugin called   O Daily quests, because there was that button, and I just change way to main menu.
But how to create it in other plugins, BattlePass, zAuctionhouse or Daily rewards plus ???
I'll be grateful for any help)

I'll try many ways to create that button, but nothing is work.
I create pictures of those menu with Oraxen, and trying to create that button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.